# AppInsights sampling to always or more often include slow calls

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

We are looking to configure AppInsights monitoring for a WebApi application. The application might have error responses in 0.5-1% of the calls. If we want to include all exceptions in AppInsights, we have the option to include exceptions always.

What I did not see in the App Insights documentation is the ability to control slow calls in a similar way. If about 2% of the API calls are slower, for e.g. an API that generally takes 2 seconds to process, might respond in 5-10 seconds for 2% of the call. We would like to be able to collect these slow calls, perhaps all or a higher sampling so there is more data to troubleshoot.

With aggressive sampling, we run the risk that these 2% calls never or rarely show up in AppInsights. For e.g. the support will not use most of the good calls to troubleshoot issues, but will be more interested to drill down into the slow ones.

With high rate of sampling, we are more likely to catch these slower calls but it adds to the cost, maintaining telemetry for a lot of normal calls, which we will not be very interested in.

Is a more fine-grained control on sampling available to meet this need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is also a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#frequently-asked-questions) about this, in this section "There are certain rare events I always want to see. How can I get them past the sampling module?":

The best way to achieve this is to write a custom [TelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor), which sets the SamplingPercentage to 100 on the telemetry item you want retained, as shown below. This ensures that all sampling techniques will ignore this item from any sampling considerations.

After you create a custom TelemetryProcessor, add the code snippet:

```
    if(somecondition, like the time is slower than 2 seconds)
    {
        ((ISupportSampling)item).SamplingPercentage = 100;
    }
```

Comment: This approach would not be ideal. For e.g. if the application has 10 APIs, each API could have different turnaround times. We wouldn't want to track the TAT for each API. Instead if Azure can automatically calculate baseline TAT for each API, and calls whose TAT is X number of standard deviations from the baseline will be treated as slow and a higher priority to capture. Some other monitoring tools like AppDynamics do this - https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Dynamic+Baselines